# mysql syntax error, same notice whatever i change

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

i'm having a problem to select all in the warehouse table and get the names of the customer and user from their tables with the id's for these names to have them from the warehouse table,

**DATABASE STRUCTURE:**

```
table 1: warehouse 
table 2: customer (City, FirstName, LastName) 
table 3: user (FirstName, LastName)

$result = mysql_query("SELECT customer.City, customer.FirstName AS customerFName, customer.LastName AS customerLName, user.FirstName AS clientFName, user.LastName AS clientLName, warehouse.*". 
"FROM warehouse". 
"INNER JOIN customer, user".
"ON warehouse.CustomerID = customer.CustomerID AND warehouse.UserID = user.UserID") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

the Notice: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON warehouse.CustomerID = customer.CustomerID AND warehouse.UserID = user.UserID'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the query  like this.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT customer.City, customer.FirstName AS customerFName, customer.LastName AS customerLName, user.FirstName AS clientFName, user.LastName AS clientLName, warehouse.* ". 
"FROM warehouse". 
" INNER JOIN customer".
" ON warehouse.CustomerID = customer.CustomerID".
" INNER JOIN user ON warehouse.UserID = user.UserID") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.City, c.FirstName AS customerFName, c.LastName AS customerLName, 
       u.FirstName AS clientFName, u.LastName AS clientLName, 
       w.* 
FROM warehouse w
INNER JOIN customer c ON w.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN user u ON w.UserID = u.UserID;
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start, 97% <sup>(a)</sup> of *all* dynamically built SQL problems can be saved if you just *print out the string before you execute it.*

In this case, you'll find spaces missing between individual words because of the way you're concatenating the strings.

Once *that's* fixed, you should realise that an `inner join` works on only one table at a time. I think what you're looking for is:

```
inner join customer on warehouse.CustomerID = customer.CustomerID 
inner join user on warehouse.UserID = user.UserID
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Figure plucked from the air. Actual value may vary.